# Node debugging remote debugging

Tags: node.js, angularjs, remote-debugging, webstorm

I have set up a Ubuntu 12.04 Virtual Box with MongoDB 2.4.8 and node. It is configured and run by Vagrant. My project skelletion was created with angular-fullstack (coffeescript client side, less, ui-router, mongoose and authentication).

After struggeling with the port forwarding for the node debugging for a bit, I have up up and running, but it is extremely slow. The connection from Webstorm to node takes abot 10 to 15 seconds. And stepping through code is a matter of several seconds for every step.

Is there something I can do to speed things up?